# PHP Regular expression - forget everything after?

Tags: php, regex

I have this url: http:www.blabla.com/x/x/x/x?username=testuser
I need a string to read this url, but forget everything and including the `?` mark.
So it becomes this: http:www.blabla.com/x/x/x/x

The reason for this is because I am making this variable:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And this code:

```
if($host == "http:www.blabla.com/x/x/x/x") {
    echo "lul";
}
```

But right now, the URL changes depending on what user is on, and it has to execute the `echo` no matter what user is on.

So I read some reges and `preg_match` etc. and I just wanted to hear your opinions or advice. How would I accomblish this the best? thanks!

Comment: You don't need a regex for this. Just use `strtok()`: `$result = strtok($url, '?');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too trivial of a task for regex.

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2)[0];
```

(Note: this assumes you're up-to-date, or at least using PHP 5.4, for the dereference to work without a temporary variable)

Comment: this seems the exact type of question tht a 100l+ rep user should be answering **not**

Comment: @tereško My point here is to guide OP away from using regexes for something that is not a regex task. https://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: ... which you can do in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Or if you must omit the get / request section just explode ? and use $host[0]